# How to order a json output via groovy?

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

I have seen something unusual with my SOAP UI script. I just want to perform an assertion that the data with is correct so I have written this code beLow:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def json =  new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
def jsonFormat = (response).toString()

def policies = [
    [x: 28, xxx: 41, xxxxx: 1, name: 'Individual 18-50', aaa: true], 
    [x: 31, xxx: 41, xxxxx: 1, name: 'Individual 51-60', aaa: true], 
    [x: 34, xxx: 41, xxxxx: 1, name: 'Individual 61-75', aaa: true], 
    [x: 37, xxx: 41, xxxxx: 1, name: 'Individual 76-85', aaa: false]
]

log.warn json.policies
log.error policies
assert json.policies == policies
```

When I look at the log.warn and log.error info, it displays the json response in the incorrect order as it display 'isActive' field first.

log.warn `json.policies` displays this:

```
[{aaa=true, xx=28, xxxxx=1, name=Individual 18-50, xxxx=41}, {aaa=true, x=31, xxxxx=1, name=Individual 51-60, xxx=41}, {aaa=true, x=34, xxxxx=1, name=Individual 61-75, xxx=41}, {aaa=true, x=37, xxxxx=1, name=Individual 76-85, xxx=41}]
```

log.error `policies` displays this:

```
[{x=28, xxx=41, xxxxx=1, name=Individual 18-50, aaa=true}, {x=31, xxx=41, xxxxx=1, name=Individual 51-60, aaa=true}, {x=34, xxxx=41, xxxxxx=1, name=Individual 61-75, aaa=true}, {x=37, xxx=41, xxxxx=1, name=Individual 76-85, aaa=false}]
```

How can I have the DTOs to be displayed within the correct order with `json.policies` so that it is displayed in the correct order as policies?

One more unusual thing, I ran the test case 10 times and the test step which this assertion checks has passed 3 out of 10 times. It should never have passed as if you compare the last DTO as the end for `policies`, it displays `isActive` as *false* which the last isActive in `json.policies` is *true*.

Comment: Json maps don't have order

Comment: @ oh ok then, may I ask then how come it sometimes passes and fails the assertion? is there something I have done incorrect in the code?

Comment: Because sometimes it comes out in the right order, and others not. You can't rely on the order

Comment: However the order shouldn't matter when comparing maps in groovy.  I assume these are not standard maps... What does `log.warn json.policies*.getClass()` and `log.warn policies*.getClass()` show you they are?  My guess is the json one is a LazyMap, and this is why they are not the same... They are different classes (containing the same data)

Comment: @BigHendo, please see the solution to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost close. But, couple of things to correct.

- you do not have to convert `json` **toString**.
- list should be sorted before comparison.
- and it does not matter in which order each map entries are shown in the log, each map can be compared.

Here is the `Script Assertion`

```
//Check if the response is empty or not
assert context.response, 'Response is empty'

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)

//Assign the policies from current response; assuming above json contains that; change below statement otherwise.
def actualPolicies = json.policies
//Expected Polities
def expectedPolicies = [
    [id: 28, providerId: 41, coverTypeId: 1, name: 'Individual 18-50', isActive: true], 
    [id: 31, providerId: 41, coverTypeId: 1, name: 'Individual 51-60', isActive: true], 
    [id: 34, providerId: 41, coverTypeId: 1, name: 'Individual 61-75', isActive: true], 
    [id: 37, providerId: 41, coverTypeId: 1, name: 'Individual 76-85', isActive: false]
]

log.info "List from response $actualPolicies"
log.info "List from policies $expectedPolicies"

//Sort the list and compare; each item is a map and using id to compare both 
assert expectedPolicies.sort{it.id} == actualPolicies.sort{it.id}, 'Both policies are not matching'
```

You can quickly the online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/BNG5nQ)</kbd> with fixed data based on your description to see it working the comparison.